# How to append a variable with dollar sign after a string match using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a variable with dollar signs in it:

```
ipvar_definitions="
var SSH_SERVERS \$HOME_NET
var FTP_SERVERS \$HOME_NET
var SIP_SERVERS \$HOME_NET
"
```

I want to append the value of this variable after a match using sed or perl or whatever one liner I can use.

When trying with sed using the code below:

```
sed   "/var SNMP_SERVERS/a ${ipvar_definitions}" /etc/snort.conf
```

I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: expected newer version of sed
```

I get this error because my variable has dollar signs in it. I'd like to solve this in a one liner using sed, perl, awk or whatever I can use.

For clarification I am posting a sample input and the expected output:

Input:

```
# List of snmp servers on your network
var SNMP_SERVERS $HOME_NET

# Configure your service ports.  This allows snort to look for attacks destined
```

Expected output:

```
# List of snmp servers on your network
var SNMP_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var SSH_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var FTP_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var SIP_SERVERS $HOME_NET

# Configure your service ports.  This allows snort to look for attacks destined
```

Comment: The error *probably* comes from your `sed` version requiring a backslash before each literal newline you want to insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gnu awk you can do this:

```
# no need to escape the $ if you use single quotes
ipvar_definitions='var SSH_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var FTP_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var SIP_SERVERS $HOME_NET'

# use awk command to insert ipvar_definitions after a line containing "var SNMP_SERVERS"
awk -v var="$ipvar_definitions" '1; /var SNMP_SERVERS/{print var}' /etc/snort.conf
```

**Output:**

```
# List of snmp servers on your network
var SNMP_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var SSH_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var FTP_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var SIP_SERVERS $HOME_NET

# Configure your service ports.  This allows snort to look for attacks destined
```

Comment: To save output of this awk command in place use: `awk -i inplace -v var="$ipvar_definitions" '1; /var SNMP_SERVERS/{print var}' /etc/snort.conf`

Comment: There's nothing gawk-specific about that command. It will become so if you add `-i inplace` of course but the OP doesn't seem to be asking for that.

Comment: I mentioned gnu awk because my OSX awk didn't like multiline variable i.e `-v var="$ipvar_definitions"`

Comment: Really? That's bizarre. I wonder if that's an OSX shell problem or an awk problem. I just tested with the default awk and GNU awk on OSX and it's an OSX awk problem as GNU awk works fine with it so the shell isn't having a problem with it. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ export ipvar_definitions='
var SSH_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var FTP_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var SIP_SERVERS $HOME_NET
'

$ perl -pe 's/.*var SNMP_SERVERS.*/$&$ENV{ipvar_definitions}/' /etc/snort.conf 
# List of snmp servers on your network
var SNMP_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var SSH_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var FTP_SERVERS $HOME_NET
var SIP_SERVERS $HOME_NET


# Configure your service ports.  This allows snort to look for attacks destined
```

Further reading: https://perldoc.perl.org/Env.html